# Is there a way to execute asynchronous code inline within a synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Whenever I look for `async`/`await` JavaScript examples called from within a synchronous thread, I always see the following structure:

```
async fun = () => {
  // async stuff like await statements
  console.log("Done!")
}

fun() // Will print "Done!" when the end of the process has been reached
```

However I've recently come across a situation where I would want to write code inline without explicitly declaring a function and then calling it (avoids passing arguments if the function is declared in a higher scope and in my opinion is cleaner). I've found this solution to work, but I don't like it as it's essentially the same thing, simply the function isn't given a name:

```
(async () => {
  // async stuff like await statements
  console.log("Done!")
}).call() // Will also print "Done!" when the end of the process has been reached
```

Is there a better way to execute inline asynchronous code ? I looked at using the `Promise` API, notably `Promise.resolve()` but it doesn't seem to execute an asynchronous function passed to it, it's quite likely I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: That is what is called an immediately invoked function expression. Useally done with `(......)()` instead of `(......).call()`

Comment: Understand that there's no way to make asynchronous mechanisms synchronous. The `async` and `await` keywords make handling Promise code cleaner, but they do not fundamentally change the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use IIFE

```
(async () => {
  // async stuff like await statements
  console.log("Done!")
})()
```

Comment: I've never thought of it that way but it's cleaner than .call(), so I'll take it! Thanks!